# How can I add an additional, custom profile to the checkout flow?

Tags: 8, commerce

In Commerce 2 I have a custom Profile to collect additional contact information that may differ from the billing/payment profile information.

I've created the new profile but cannot figure out how to add it to the checkout flow. Any ideas?

Comment: OP found a solution using the, commerce_profile_pane module.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_profile_pane